# Is this a valid usage of ServiceStack Redis?

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack

I am new to Redis (using it at a hosted service) and want to use it as a demonstration / sandbox data storage for lists.

I use the following piece of code. It works - for me. But is it a valid (and not completely bad practice) usage for a small web site with several (up to 100) concurrent users (for a small amount of data - up to 1000 list items)?

I'm using static connection and a static redisclient typed list like this:

```
public class MyApp
{   
    private static ServiceStack.Redis.RedisClient redisClient;

    public static IList<Person> Persons;
    public static IRedisTypedClient<Person> PersonClient;

    static MyApp()
    {
        redisClient = new RedisClient("nnn.redistogo.com", nnn) { Password = "nnn" };
        PersonClient = redisClient.GetTypedClient<Person>();
        Persons = PersonClient.Lists["urn:names:current"];
    }
}
```

Doing this I have a very easy to use persistent list of data, which is exactly what I want when I'm building / demonstrating the basic blocks of my application.

```
foreach (var person in MyApp.Persons) ...
```

Adding a new person:

```
MyApp.Persons.Add(new Person { Id = MyApp.PersonClient.GetNextSequence(), Name = "My Name" });
```

My concern is (currently) not the fact that I am loading the complete list into memory at appstart, but rather the possibility that my connection to the redis host is not following good standards - or that there is some other issue that I'm not aware of.

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Actually when you use `PersonClient.Lists["urn:names:current"]` you're actually storing a reference to a RedisClient Connection which is not thread safe. It's ok if it's in a GUI or Console app, but not ideal in a multi-threaded web app. In most scenarios you want to be using a thread safe connection factory i.e.

```
var redisManager = new PooledRedisClientManager("localhost:6379");
```

Which acts very much like a database connection pool. So whenever you want to access the RedisClient works like:

```
using (var redis = redisManager.GetClient())
{
    var allItems = redis.As<Person>().Lists["urn:names:current"].GetAll();
}
```

Note: `.As<T>` is a shorter alias for `.GetTypedClient<T>`
Another convenient short-cut to execute a typed client from a redisManager is:

```
var allItems = redisManager.ExecAs<Person>(r => r.Lists["urn:names:current"].GetAll());
```

I usually prefer to pass around `IRedisClientsManager` in my code so it doesn't hold a RedisClient connection but can access it whenever it needs to.

Comment: I see. One thing I don't quite understand is how to handle the updates between the C# List to the Redis storage. I found it quite conveniant with the open connection where I always have the full list in my app and don't (?) even need to handle updates explicitly. With your method you're fetching the list again each time you need it?

Comment: Another question : how to pass a password with the help of ClientsManager?

Comment: @joeriks If it's a GUI app, it's fine to keep and use a single connection, connections in Redis are super cheap. Using the redisManager, you would need to cast to (RedisNativeClient) to set a password and ReConnect(). Tho Redis should only be accessible from an Intranet, and its not that common to require a password. You don't need to get the entire list each time (I was just showing you an example call) from a manager. You can still update a single item with `redis.As<Person>().Lists["key"][3]=newValue`, or `SetItemInList` for full api see: http://servicestack.net/img/Redis-annotated.png

Comment: Ok, thanks. Yeah, the password, I'm experimenting with using redis at a hosted service (Redis to go) to get up'n running quick but I realize self hosting would be the best for a real solution.

Comment: @mythz how can we set password to a new PooledRedisClientsManager()

Comment: You can supply the password in the host URI like: password@localhost:6379.

Comment: @mythz Please , Where can I find all the **documentation**  for those all new commands e.g.`.As<Person>().`.... I now the previous version (which is not working anymore) where `GetTypedClient<>` was used instead... can you please provide link ?>

Answer (score 0):

There is an example project [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/636730/Distributed-Caching-using-Redis)