# ServiceStack Caching/Session lock

Tags: c#, session, servicestack

I'm using ServiceStack's session feature (that's using memory caching), and I try to access a key in the session object, modify it and then save the session:

```
var filesList = Session.Get<List<string>>("NewRequestUploadedFiles");
filesList.Add(fileName);
Session["NewRequestUploadedFiles"] = filesList;
```

This code can be called parallely through multiple concurrent requests from the client, so locking on this key is required.
Is there any built-in way to achieve locking on ISession?

For now I use memory caching, but in the future I would like to change the caching provider to Redis, so if there is any generic way, it is preferred.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to just use the locking built in. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8096551/215502

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using [ServiceStack's typed sessions](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions) since writes are atomic.

Otherwise if you want, you can maintain [distributed locks with Redis](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/wiki/RedisLocks). If it's only a single host in memory you can just use C# standard locking semantics.

Comment: thanks. i'm interested in locking for the read+write operations together. not only for the write. so I guess that c# lock will be the solution for the single host in memory, and Redis.AcquireLock will be the solution in the future, when I move to multiple web servers. I just hoped that it will be possible to write generic code that I wouldn't need to rewrite when I'll move to Redis.