# ServiceStack Redis CRUD

Tags: redis, servicestack

First time using ServiceStack Redis. I looked around the web and could not find a very basic crud example. Closest I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094162/is-this-a-valid-usage-of-servicestack-redis) and [this](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/tree/master/tests/ServiceStack.Redis.Tests/Examples). Just wondering If I'm doing it right. Thanks.

Note : Assume that I am using a using statement. I took it out because StackOverflow complained that I had 'too much code'.
using (var client = RedisManager.GetClient().GetTypedClient())

```
public class TestUser
{
    public string UserName;
}

    public IEnumerable<TestUser> GetAll()
    {
        return client.Lists["Users"].AsQueryable();
    }

    public void UpdateAll(IEnumerable<TestUser> users)
    {
        var list = client.Lists["Users"];
        foreach (var testUser in users)
        {
            client.SetEntry(testUser.UserName, testUser);
            client.Store(testUser);

            if (!list.Contains(testUser))
                list.Add(testUser);
        }
        client.SaveAsync();
    }

    public TestUser Get(string username)
    {
        return client.GetById(username);
    }

    public void Update(TestUser model)
    {
        client.SetEntry(model.UserName, model);
        client.Store(model);
        client.SaveAsync();
    }

    public void Delete(string username)
    {
        client.DeleteById(username);
            client.SaveAsync();
    }
```

**Edit :** Looking at [StackOverFlow Example](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/blob/master/src/RedisStackOverflow/RedisStackOverflow.ServiceInterface/IRepository.cs#L123). Im confused about the Id's. line 102 generates a magic string alias and line 116 creates a numerical id. What is an alias and what is an Id? When I get the entity (line 123) which one am I using? Can the id be a string? Is there a way to get the entry using a string id? Should I convert to longs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many of the [ServiceStack live demos](http://www.servicestack.net/#livedemos) have Redis CRUD examples. The easiest is the Redis back-end of the [Backbone Todos implementation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/blob/master/src/Backbone.Todos/Global.asax.cs). Also look at [Redis StackOverflow implementation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/blob/master/src/RedisStackOverflow/RedisStackOverflow.ServiceInterface/IRepository.cs) which is a good example showing how to create manual indexes to maintain referential data.

Comment: In the StackOverflow example line 102 generates a magic string alias and line 116 creates a numerical id. What is an alias and what is an Id? When I get the entity (line 123) which one am I using? Can the id be a string? Is there a way to get the entry using a string id? Should I convert to longs? Thanks for your support.

Comment: The "magic string alias" is a custom index that allows you to look up the user by name (id is automatically maintained), like line 110 does.

Comment: @mythz, what is the purpose of "id" comparing to a regular key ?